# export WMTS tiles as MBTiles with reprojection

Tags: qgis, coordinate-system, wmts, mbtiles

I need to export tiles from a WMTS server to the MBTiles format. The server is not public, but I have access to it and permission to export a specific portion of the tiles. The problem I have seems to come from the different projections:

- The WMTS server uses UTM zone 38N (EPSG:23038)
- The exported MBTiles needs to be in WGS84 spherical mercator (EPSG:3857)

What's the easiest approach to achieve this, and with which tools?

I already tried loading the WMTS source in QGIS and using QTiles. This works, but the resulting tiles are rendered poorly, I guess due to a sub-optimal reprojection algorithm.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've been able to get this to work using [MapProxy](https://mapproxy.org/). MapProxy is a powerful tool for cases like this, because it allows you to define everything through a configuration file instead of having to click through a UI.

MapProxy supports [raster re-projection](https://mapproxy.org/docs/1.8.0/configuration_examples.html#reprojecting-tiles) and various storage formats including [mbtiles](https://mapproxy.org/docs/1.8.0/caches.html#mbtiles).

The individual steps to export a certain area are as follows:

- configure the data source as [source](https://mapproxy.org/docs/1.8.0/sources.html) and test it through the MaprProxy stand-alone server
- define a [cache](https://mapproxy.org/docs/1.8.0/caches.html) in the same projection as the source
- define a second cache with the target projection, use the first cache as source
- define the area that should be exported as polygon (e.g. GeoJSON)
- add the GeoJSON to the seed configuration as [coverage](https://mapproxy.org/docs/1.8.0/coverages.html)
- define a [seed task](https://mapproxy.org/docs/1.8.0/seed.html) for the second cache using the specified coverage

Now run the seed task. When it is finished, the exported mbtiles file can be found in the `cache_data` directory.